# XML Parsing using Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I have an XML of following format. I want to extract the 'title' and 'submenu' tags and create a menu bar structure out of it as in the image below.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<homemenu>
<rootmenu>
<title>Products</title>
<submenu1>
    <title>Articulated1</title>
    <submenu2>
        <name>Arti1</name>
        <email>Culated1</email>
    </submenu2>
</submenu1>
<submenu1>
    <title>BackHoles1</title>
    <submenu2>
        <name>Back1</name>
        <email>Holes1</email>
    </submenu2>
</submenu1>
</rootmenu>
<rootmenu>
<title>Services</title>
<submenu1>
    <title>VolvoParts2</title>
    <submenu2>
        <name>Volvo2</name>
        <email>Parts2</email>
    </submenu2>
</submenu1>
<submenu1>
    <title>PartsOnline2</title>
    <submenu2>
        <name>Parts2</name>
        <email>Online2</email>
    </submenu2>
</submenu1>
</rootmenu>
</homemenu>
```

[image]

Please suggest me how could i do it.

Thanks..

Comment: your xml and image does not seems to have any relation .. explain more . btw i am not the one who downvoted you .. but still a guy with 106 reputation should know how to ask a question in stackoverflow

Comment: @AJ you r absolutely correct bro, but i am just new to it. and not able to figure out how to do and proceed. finally i asked this quest. i know, it ll get downvoted but what else i can do...I have given a sample example of image when i have parse the xml file same like text in the image...

Comment: okay .. but sorry buddy .. i am not a android guy .. i was trying to help you improve your answer .. only then others will be able to help you

Comment: @AJ thanks for suggestion could you please let me know how could i ask same question in much better way.. if u could edit my quest please i ll very thankful to u..

Comment: so where do you have this xml .. is this a file or in the form of string?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49675/discussion-between-james-and-a-j)

Comment: @James: Hope below answer is working fine for you.

Comment: @anubhava i was on Holi vacation, so not able to reply... I tried the below code actually i m beginner, but not able to get the below code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use jquery's parseXML function,

```
  var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
  $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
  $title = $xml.find( "title" );

  alert($title.text());
```

Refer 
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: where is your xml file ? if its @ server, you can use ajax to get the data

Comment: Then, you can try this,
`$.get('allTasks.xml', function(data) {
    $xml = $( data ),
    $title = $xml.find( "title" );

    alert($title.text());
}`

Comment: @ Robin C Samuel bro i m just beginner, i could not understand much your syntax. please if u could give me one example, which parse the xml file like above image, i will be very thank full to you

Comment: hi bro u there..please reply for me

Comment: @James, sorry. I was away. You can use jquery get function to read a file. $.get('pathtofile/filename.xml', function(data) { }); . you'll get the data inside that function

Comment: hi bro u there. i have created completed html design and now tell me i have one xml file how should i parse it

Comment: you answer is correct but please i need some help, when i want to read all data from xml file

Comment: I've commented above, using a `$.get` method to do the same from an xml file.