# Using "?" in htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect

mysite.com/vids.php?id=265s2g

to

mysite.com/watch?v=265s2g

I have tried

```
RewriteRule ^watch?v=(.*)$ vids.php?id=$1
```

But gives me a not found error. What is the correct way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match query string in rewrite rule. Use it this way:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^watch$ vids\.php?id=$1 [L,R,NC]
```

Comment: For which URL does it give 404?

Comment: When I try to display for ex: mysite.com/watch?v=Pv_qMHr8e9o

Comment: Now it says The requested URL /home/downloa8/public_html/www.mysite.com/vids.php was not found on this server. Its dramatically adding additional url http://www.site.com/home/downloa8/public_html/www.site.com/vids.php?id=

Comment: Ok solved it with adding rewrite base / .But there is a problem now, it displays but id seems empty.

Comment: @anubhava bro need help i hope you can give suggestion in it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375350/xml-parsing-in-phongap-application-using-jquery-mobile

Comment: Just came back online, I will sure check other question.

Comment: @user3304007: If you can place your latest .htaccess in your question I can investigate and suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule to redirect

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^vids.php(.*)$ watch?v=%1 [L,R,NC]
```

The above rule will redirect,

`http://anysite.com/vids.php?id=265s2g`

to

`http://anysite.com/watch?v=265s2g`

Try the test at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/